# Next three holidays for any given country - MySQL or API?

Tags: php, mysql, api, floating

I am not very back-end savvy and could really use someone wiser's guidance.

I would like to have a site that lists the next three holidays in any given country, based on the current date.

I haven't found a free way to query a database for this information. I don't mind creating my own table in my MySQL database, but I can't think of a way to update it daily (other than manually).

I found [this](http://pear.php.net/package/Date_Holidays) through a Stack Overflow search, but my eyes went crossed on how to implement this on my grid service server.

Could someone shed some light on how this could be done? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not every country, but it's a pretty great free resource!
http://kayaposoft.com/enrico